# PostgreSQL - Assigning window function to alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to set ROW_NUMBER()... as an alias so I can reference it in the OFFSET. e.g. `OFFSET some_alias - 1`. I need to get a single row including the ROW_NUMBER() from a larger query. Here's my working code (gets correct ROW_NUMBER(), but isn't offset by the right amount):

```
WITH FirstQuery AS (
    SELECT "RepInitials", COUNT("OrderStatus"), ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY COUNT("OrderStatus") DESC)
    FROM "tblBulkSalesQuery"
    WHERE "OrderStatus" = 'CMC'
    GROUP BY "RepInitials"
)
SELECT "RepInitials", COUNT("OrderStatus"), ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY COUNT("OrderStatus") DESC)
    FROM "tblBulkSalesQuery"
    WHERE "OrderStatus" = 'CMC'
    GROUP BY "RepInitials"
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from (
    SELECT "RepInitials", 
           COUNT("OrderStatus") as order_status_count, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT("OrderStatus") DESC) as rn
    FROM "tblBulkSalesQuery"
    WHERE "OrderStatus" = 'CMC'
    GROUP BY "RepInitials"
) as t
where rn = 1
```

**Edit**:

The `t` is an alias for the nested select ("derived table"). PostgreSQL requires each derived table to get it's own "name" and that can only be done by assigning a alias.

It's pretty much the same as:

```
with t as (
  ... here goes the real select ...
)
select *
from t 
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I'm honestly not sure either. I really need to start learning more about SQL. Thanks so much for your quick response! :)

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly, but would you mind clarifying something for me? What does the `t` after the from mean?

Comment: @ktross: One could be more verbose and write `AS t` which is recommended for column aliases but not necessary for [table aliases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: good point. Although I always do it for columns for some strange reason I never do it for derived tables ;)